# If I call Left([col], x) on an NVARCHAR(max) column, is it always safe to save the output in an NVARCHAR(x) column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, nvarchar

The common misconception that the argument to `NVARCHAR(x)` is a character count has bitten me many times today. I am asking this question in the interest of exploring the topic further.

Consider an `NVARCHAR(max)` column. Call it `FOO_PERM_COL` from table `FOO_PERM_TABLE`. Will the following code ever fail?

```sql
CREATE TABLE #FOO_TEMP_TABLE
(
   FOO_TEMP_COL NVARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #FOO_TEMP_TABLE
SELECT Left(FOO_PERM_COL, 1000)
FROM FOO_PERM_TABLE
```

If the code can fail (i.e. throw an exception), I'd like to see some examples that make it fail. If collations matter, then please say so. If the code cannot fail, then I'd like the argument supporting this to be backed up with reference to the documentation.

I expect that `LEFT`'s documentation does not tell the full story. The documentation says that it trims your column down to the specified number of characters, but [this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Wj-P30p7) has me suspect that it does more than that. If `LEFT` only cut down to the specified number of characters, then I would expect `SELECT LEFT(N'', 1)` to return the unicode character that you put in. Dbfiddle says that it doesn't. I think that the following line in the documentation is of the utmost relevance to that point

> The *integer_expression* parameter counts a UTF-16 surrogate character as one character.

Comment: Define fail. (Exception, or invalid/broken data?)

Comment: @jarlh Exception. I'll edit.

Comment: You really should consider using https://dba.stackexchange.com/ for your technical database questions

Comment: @DaleK You're right... force of habit.

Comment: Just make sure [you know what `LEFT(col,x)` actually means](https://dbfiddle.uk/17Hg-cJ0). Sometimes it's not `x` characters.

Comment: @Stuckat1337 I think we've hit on the same point at the same time. I think my edit makes the same point as your link does.

Comment: For even more fun try REVERSE(N'your weird char') and see how it fairs. I'm not sure UTF8 has these issues, but UTF16 has always been kinda broken

Comment: @siggemannen I know how byte pairs work, so I can imagine what horrors you have in mind. I think that might be safe under an `_SC` collation, but I wouldn't risk it.

Comment: The `LEFT` function operates on characters but what constitutes characters depends on the collation in use. db<>fiddle doesn't do what you expect because its not using an *_SC (Supplementary Characters) Default Database collation, so it's treating `NCHAR` and `NVARCHAR` data types as having UCS-2 encoding. Compare the outputs of `SELECT LEFT(N'' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS, 1)` and `SELECT LEFT(N'' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC, 1)`.

Comment: SQL Server uses alternate string functions when *_SC collations are involved, have a read through [Supplementary Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver16#Supplementary_Characters).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Yeah that looks pretty bad https://dbfiddle.uk/lZymXg40

Comment: So in the format requested in the question... https://dbfiddle.uk/93WNT4Fw

Comment: @Charlieface bear in mind that the dimension to `NCHAR` and `NVARCHAR` types still assumes UCS-2 encoding regardless of the collation. i.e.: an `NCHAR(1)` data type is allocated 2 bytes so will still be unable to hold a Supplementary Character because that requires 4 bytes of storage. (Welcome to the joys of variable-length encodings.)

Comment: Can you specify collation being used? That will give you a more precise/specific answer.

Comment: @SalmanA No. I've included everything that I intended to. If the answer depends on collation, then I'd be overjoyed at an answer that tells me that.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a table having columns with litteral datatypes (CHAR, NCHAR, VARCHAR, NVARCHAR) the database collation is used to enforce the colum datatype.

You can see that in :

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, COLLATION_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

SQL Server use UTF16 encoding that have no emitcon by default, but can add emoticons only if you use a SC (Supplmential Characters) collation.

List of SC collations can be found with :

```
SELECT *
FROM   sys.fn_helpcollations() 
WHERE  description LIKE '%supplementary characters%'
```

As a test :

```
CREATE DATABASE DB_TEST_COLLATION COLLATE SQL_EBCDIC277_2_CP1_CS_AS
GO
USE DB_TEST_COLLATION 
GO
SELECT LEFT(N'', 1 )
```

Will return : �

```
CREATE DATABASE DB_TEST_COLLATION2 COLLATE Albanian_100_CI_AS_SC
GO
USE DB_TEST_COLLATION2
GO
SELECT LEFT(N'', 1 )
```

Will RETURN

CQFD

Comment: This doesn't clearly answer the question of if the given code will ever fail.

Comment: As the ISO standard SQL says, when in a string passed as an argument is out of the scope of the defined character set or collation the return will always be "?", but no exception with an error message.